# Best way to index an "UPDATE" statement with "WHERE" in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel & MySQL and I have this "UPDATE" statement that is taking really long to execute and I am trying to optimize it the best way possible.

Here is my query that is taking around 700ms:

```sql
UPDATE
  table_1
SET
  woman_id = 48,
  table_1.updated_at = '2020-08-26 12:18:48'
WHERE
  woman_id is null
  AND last_date >= '2020-08-26'
  AND man_id = 1
ORDER BY
  last_date ASC
LIMIT
  100
```

I added an index for (man_id, woman_id, last_date) to reach 700ms, while it reaches 4s without the index.
The table contains around 90k records.

Any ideas on how to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, The more columns you update, the slow it is but there are some ways; One of them is in PHP side updating data by chunk. Another one is to Mysql ANALYZE TABLE table_1 to optimize the index. Also since you are updating data, you can remove order by clause.

```
    $result = $db->rawquery("select * from table1 WHERE 
    woman_id is null AND last_date >= '2020-08-26' AND man_id = 1");
    
    // Chunk Results
    $chunk = array_chunk($result, 5000);

         foreach ($chunk as $chunk_arr) {

                  $tmp_arr = array();
                  foreach ($chunk_arr as $segment) {
                       $tmp_arr [] = $segment;
                  }
                  
                  $sql = "insert into table_1 (
                                         colum1,colum2, and so on
                                         ) values ";
                            
                  $array_keys = array_keys($tmp_arr);
                  $last_key = end($array_keys);

                  foreach ($tmp_arr as $key => $data) {
                  if ($last_key == $key) {
                  $sql .= "(" . implode(",", $data) . ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE woman_id=VALUES(48), updated_at=VALUES('2020-08-26 12:18:48') ";
                  } else {
                  $sql .= "(" . implode(",", $data) . "),";
                  }
                  }

                 

                 $db->rawQuery($sql);
                 unset($tmp_arr);
       }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the PHP side thing

Answer (score 0):

Consider this strategy,

Add an index for (last_date, man_id, woman_id)

change the
WHERE
last_date >= '2020-08-26'
AND man_id = 1
AND woman_id is null

let us know the results.

REMOVE the other multi column index.

Comment: it is now taking 6s to complete a LIMIT 50, that was actually worse than the old index

Comment: @PedroMarthon  Please post text results of EXPLAIN of the 6s processing. Consider running ANALYZE table_name to ensure indexes are current before running with EXPLAIN SELECT ....